# No line number found known for in gdb

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, x86-64

I have compiled my own *glibc*, which produced `libc.so`. I loaded the `libc.so` file in gdb by doing `gdb -q ./libc.so`. However, when I try to find the location of a function by doing `list function_name`, I get the error message, `No line number known for function_name`. Note that I use the -g flag for compiling *glibc*. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you see this function in `info functions` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you even debug a .so by itself? What I would try is to do is `gdb executable_using_my_libc`. Then this should load glibc and so on.

Comment: "Can you even debug a .so by itself" -- yes, it works perfectly fine (not for running, but for `info func`, `list foo`, `info source`, etc. `libc.so.6` is a special case: you can even run it.